# Allow to check only one checkbox in Oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I created classic report with check boxes using apex_item.checkbox .I want to know how to allow to check only checkbox.That is if i click more than checkbox alert message should display.Please help me out

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually radio buttons are used to allow only one selection out of many.

Comment: Hi rene thanks for your reply ,can you help out iam new and learning ,for learning i want to know those things

Comment: While you could do it with a Dynamic Action and logic , it's better to simply not do it and use radio buttons instead. Many examples of why and when to use them on the web, like:https://www.nngroup.com/articles/checkboxes-vs-radio-buttons/

Comment: HI joe thanks for your reply ,can you tell me the steps to do it with dynamic action and logic

Comment: Hi all,just i want you know how to add JavaScript in oracle apex ,so tell me how to do that

Comment: Hello Ragu, since you're new to apex it might be useful to tell us what the functionality is you are trying to achieve. New users are tempted to code functionality the way they're used to but there might be an easier way to achieve the same result in apex.

Comment: Hi koen Lostrie, i created an classic report of employee details with apex_item.checkbox and if  i click more than one checkbox it should not allow to check more than one and display alert message that "we should  not select more than one employee "

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this via dynamic actions then you will want do a dynamic action on event Change, Selection Type jQuery Selector and the jQuery Selector being input[name = "something"]

This something you can figure out by running the page as is, and if you click F12 on your keyboard, the console will open. Then select the element that is your checkbox and find its name and this should be your "something". Play around with this to make it work(set the DA to run an alert or something to see when its triggered).

Then perhaps have a page item that is filled when this DA runs, and then if the page item is already filled and the DA runs, throw up an error saying you cant do this.

Or if you want to clear the previously checked box, you could save the name of currently checked box in the page item. And have the DA do a javascript function that clears the value in the field in the page item.

Basically have the DA get the name of the checked box from the item where you store it, and do some dynamic javascript. When I needed to do something similair I created a var in javascript that was formed like $s(" + checked_box + ", "");  assembling this with concat. And then do an eval(this_concacted_instruction).

I hope my ramblings guide you to a solution. I remember the first time I was working with this stuff I took a week to get one page sorted(although it was a bit more difficult than your problem), but it felt sooo good when I got it done. So keep on trying.

GLHF