# Retaining value in forms after submitting process i oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I created an dynamic to display values in field based on other filed value .On selection of field the page gets submitted,since page is submitted the values is fields get cleared,so how to display value in forms even after submit in oracle apex

Comment: Gonna guess that this is to do with source of the items being null.

Comment: Can anyone help me out for this page post .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58375533/allow-to-check-only-one-checkbox-in-oracle-apex?noredirect=1#comment103110372_58375533

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to page **processes** and look at what they do, as it seems that it (or they) are resetting page cache. There's probably a process named `reset page` whose type is **clear session state**; disable it to see whether it is responsible for that. If so, either leave it disabled or delete it (if you don't need it).

Furthermore, on the same page you'll see **branches** (if any) - check it (them) as well, as they might also be clearing page cache. See its *target*, in there you'll see the "Clear session state" section.

Comment: Hi Littlefoot thanks for your help and  there is no resetting process and clear cache in page processing